# Right way to use function field() in yii2

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I am writing REST API for my project.

**field()** function in my Model:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();

    // remove fields that contain sensitive information
    unset($fields['media'], $fields['content']);

    return $fields;
}
```

I have a 2 action:

`/api/resources` - get all resources lists

This api return:

```
"items":
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "title": "tset",
        "image": "1437537044.png",
        "ins_date": "2015-07-22 00:00:00",
        "count": 20
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "category_id": 1,
        "title": "tset",
        "image": "1437537176.png",
        "ins_date": "2015-07-22 00:00:00",
        "count": 0
    },
```

`/api/resources/view?id=1` - get all information about resource ID=1

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "title": "tset",
    "image": "1437537044.png",
    "ins_date": "2015-07-22 00:00:00",
    "count": 21
}
```

I get all resources, but I want to get all fields when I call `actionView($id)` like this:

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "title": "tset",              // I want to get response with this 
    "content": "test",            //and this fields
    "media": "test",
    "image": "1437537044.png",
    "ins_date": "2015-07-22 00:00:00",
    "count": 22
}
```

HOw can solve this problem? Help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. use subclass of models with different fields()
2. [use **Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7098#issuecomment-163775985)

   ```
   public function fields()
   {
       if(Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'controller/action'){
           return ['field_1','field_2','field_3','field_4'];
       }else{
           return ['field_1','field_3'];
       }
   }
   ```
3. [Extended **yii\rest\Serializer** change **init()** and **getRequestedFields()**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7098#issuecomment-215423462)